# How is the loss computed from the batch and round?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[This is cross-posted from the forum.](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2160842)

I am trying to just reproduce the loss computed during training a very simple network. In this case the loss is just the standard L2 loss function.

Start with some data to learn a sin function:

```
trainingData = Table[x -> Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100.0}];
```

Next, create a very simple network:

```
chain = NetChain[{10, Tanh, 1}];
```

Normally, I would train it just like this:

```
result = NetTrain[chain, trainingData, All]
```

But to reproduce the loss, I need to know what the batch data was used at each iteration. So let's also save that:

```
lastBatchIn = {};
lastBatchOut = {};
lastBatchLossList = None;

appendBatch = Block[{},
    (* Save the last two batch data *)

    AppendTo[lastBatchIn, Normal[#BatchData["Input"]]];
    AppendTo[lastBatchOut, Normal[#BatchData["Output"]]];
    If[Length[lastBatchIn] > 2,
     lastBatchIn = lastBatchIn[[-2 ;;]];
     lastBatchOut = lastBatchOut[[-2 ;;]];
     ];

    (* Save the last two losses for these batches *)

    lastBatchLossList = #BatchLossList[[-2 ;;]];
    ] &;

result = NetTrain[chain, trainingData, All, 
  TrainingProgressFunction -> appendBatch]
```

Here I have create a function to save the #BatchData and the #BatchLossList for the last two examples. The factor 2 comes from the fact that I see it is using 2 batches for each round of training.

Now to the question:

The loss of the last round is reported as this:

```
Print["Last round loss reported: ", result["RoundLoss"]]
(* Last round loss reported: 6.05732*10^-6 *)
```

I can reproduce this from the stored loss list for each batch. Since every round contains two batches, I average the two:

```
Print["Mean round loss recalculated: ", Mean[lastBatchLossList], 
  " from loss of the last 2 batches: ", lastBatchLossList];
(* Mean round loss recalculated: 6.05732*10^-6 from loss of the last 2 batches: {4.61266*10^-6,7.50198*10^-6} *)
```

Great! Now I want to recompute it by feeding the actual batch data into the network:

```
trained = result["TrainedNet"];
mb1 = Mean[(trained[lastBatchIn[[1]]] - lastBatchOut[[1]])^2];
mb2 = Mean[(trained[lastBatchIn[[2]]] - lastBatchOut[[2]])^2];
Print["Mean round loss recomputed: ", 0.5*(mb1 + mb2), 
  " from last 2 batches: ", mb1, " ", mb2];
(* Mean round loss recomputed: 5.77591*10^-6 from last 2 batches: 5.35384*10^-6 6.19799*10^-6 *)
```

It's definitely not the same. It may be close, but I want to figure out how to get the exact same result. How can I reproduce the loss exactly with the trained network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Looks like a bug: incorrect reported BatchIndices and BatchData.

```
SeedRandom[0];
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {16, 3}];
Y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {16, 1}];

net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[10], LinearLayer[1]}, "Input" -> 3] // NetInitialize;

saveInfo[assoc_] := Module[
  {},
  AppendTo[batchIndices, assoc["BatchIndices"]];
  AppendTo[batchLoss, assoc["BatchLoss"]];
  AppendTo[trainedNet, assoc["Net"]];
  ]

report[batchSize_] := Module[
  {},
  
  batchIndices = {};
  batchLoss = {};
  trainedNet = {};
  
  NetTrain[net, X -> Y, MaxTrainingRounds -> 2, 
   BatchSize -> batchSize, LossFunction -> MeanSquaredLossLayer[], 
   TrainingProgressFunction -> {saveInfo, 
     "Interval" -> Quantity[1, "Round"]}];
  
  Print@batchLoss;
  Print@MeanSquaredLossLayer[][<|
     "Input" -> net@X[[batchIndices[[1]]]], 
     "Target" -> Y[[batchIndices[[1]]]]|>];
  Print@MeanSquaredLossLayer[][<|
     "Input" -> trainedNet[[1]]@X[[batchIndices[[2]]]], 
     "Target" -> Y[[batchIndices[[2]]]]|>];
  ]
```

Size of the data = 16 and batch = 16:

```
report[16]
```

> {0.484094,0.476693}

> 0.484094

> 0.476693

Incorrect here:

```
report[8]
```

> {0.633787,0.312369}

> 0.642032

> 0.316417

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. Hoping someone from Wolfram will clarify if it indeed is a bug....